# duplicate files during packaging of APK

Tags: android, jar, packaging

I just started Android programming. I tried to build an application with several 3rd party jars.

When packaging the app, I got an error "duplicate files during packaging of APK". The reason is there are some files with same names in the META-INF directories (the content of the files is not the same - so there need to be different versions).

How does Android packaging work? Does Android just unpack all jars from the libs folder and then put **everything** in the APK? Is this APK just one big jar?

Answer (score 0):

an apk is like a jar just a zip-container. You can control packaging like this when you use gradle.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'asm-license.txt'
    exclude 'LICENSE'
    exclude 'NOTICE'
}
```

The above solves the duplicate files problem for assertj for me

Comment: No that doesn't solve the problem, because the content in those files is different (in my case). Just imagine bundle1.jar, with a META-INF/spring/beans.xml. And bundle2.jar, also with a META-INF/spring/beans.xml. Both contain Spring beans - but DIFFERENT ones. Simply excluding those files will break the code.

Comment: OK didn't know that part of your problem. For me it solved all duplicate file problems